# Get the meta description and page title on any page in Magento

Tags: php, magento, metadata, title

How can I get the meta description and page title of any page in Magento (product page, category page, CMS page and any other page).  This is for Magento 1.9.

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
if( Mage::registry('current_product') ){  // product page
    $product = Mage::registry('current_product');
    $title = $product->getMetaTitle();
    $descr = $product->getDescription();
}elseif( Mage::registry('current_category') ){  // category page
    $category = Mage::registry('current_category');
    $title = $category->getTitle();
    $descr = $category->getDescription();
}else{  // CMS / any other page
    $title = $this->getTitle();
    $descr = $this->getDescription();
}
```

But this isnt working in every case. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi Jimmery. Did you also solve this problem? Was my answer helpful?

Comment: your answer definitely helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the page title on any page, use:

```
$title = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle()
```

To get the meta description on any page, use:

```
$descr = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getDescription()
```