# How to get meta description with custom variable in magento

Tags: php, magento, meta

I'm brand new in magento so I apologize if my question is dumb.

I need to show the metadescription in the top of my page in a block with a custom variable. Is this even possible ?

I've searched around and i think this post is what I should do. But I can't get it to work. [LINK TO POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481325/get-the-meta-description-and-page-title-on-any-page-in-magento/35481491)

This is what i wrote in the "Variable HTML Value" field:

> < ?php  $descr = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getDescription()
>   ;  echo $descr; ?>

Comment: Are you trying to do this within the admin panel, or within a template?

Answer (score 0):

`<?php $headBlock = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head'); echo $description=$headBlock->getDescription(); ?>`please use this code

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it was very helpfull