# How to get the page title and meta description of any page in Magento?

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I would to get the page title and meta description of any product page in Magento. So I created a new Controller and added a new function:

```
public function getInfoAction()
{
    $title = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
    $descr = $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getDescription();
}
```

The error I'm getting the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getBlock() on null

How can I get these information?

Comment: $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();  Just use the variable $this for the title

Comment: echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();   This gives me this error    Fatal error: Call to a member function getTitle() on boolean

Comment: Are you using magento 2 or 1.9? Possible Duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35481325/get-the-meta-description-and-page-title-on-any-page-in-magento

Comment: I'm using 1.9. I've seen this post. I've tried it but it's not working.